# What happens when we condition on different time indexes in arma type models?

Tags: econometrics

For instance I want to calculate the covariance of $y_t$ given different information sets, what happens when we only have information available until $t-1$ and $t$? What is the difference ?

$cov(y_t|t-1,y_t|t)$

Comment: I suggest to move this to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions). There is a higher concentration of questions of this type and probably more experts to answer them.

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to define conditional covariance with two rather than one set of conditioning information. $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1}|I_{t-h})$ is well understood; e.g. $\text{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-1}|I_{t-1})=0$ since $y_{t-1}$ is a constant given $I_{t-1}$, and covariance between a random variable and a constant must be zero. Meanwhile, what is $\text{Cov}(y_t|I_{t-j},y_{t-1}|I_{t-k})$ supposed to mean?

Comment: As Richard said, I don't think that what one conditions on makes a difference because the covariance is a function of the model parameters and not the realized data. Take the AR(1) for example, That expression given is still the variance of $y_t$ no matter whether one is at time $t$ or time $t-1$.

Comment: @markleeds, I did not (mean to) say that what one conditions on does not makes a difference. We can condition covariance on different information sets and get different results.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: I guess that's possible. I can't think of an example off the top of my head.